# Retrieving group of particular contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to retrieve the contact details along with the group which it belongs to. I got the code to list all the contact groups in the phone.

```
Cursor groupC = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 

while (groupC.moveToNext()) { 
    String groupid =
        groupC.getString(groupC.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
    Log.e("myTag", groupid); 
    String grouptitle =
        groupC .getString(groupC.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE));
    Log.e("myTag", grouptitle);
}
groupC.close();
```

Then I tried to query for a particular contact by using its id but it always shows `There is no such column...`.

```
Cursor groupC = getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+"= ?",
    new String[]{id},
    null);
```

where id is

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
```

How to query the group using a particular contact id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.we should pass the raw contact-id and the correct mime type.

```
  String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID
            + "="
            + Integer.parseInt(id)
            + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
            + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'";

    Cursor cursor = ctx
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null,
                    null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    Log.e("Count is:", ""+ cursor.getCount());
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        groupid = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1));
        Log.e("groupid", groupid);
        builder.append(groupid);

    }String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID
            + "="
            + Integer.parseInt(id)
            + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE
            + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'";

    Cursor cursor = ctx
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, null,
                    null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    Log.e("Count is:", ""+ cursor.getCount());
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        groupid = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1));
        Log.e("groupid", groupid);
        break;
    }
```

A contact may be in more than one group,here it retrivr its first group pnly.

I think this may be useful to somebody...

Comment: it has to be done this way because the GroupMembership doesn't have a URI, only a MIME type. Why did Google decide this was good??